# FFMPEG: extract images from video with fixed interval, first few frames messed up

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I wanted to extract some frames from a video with a fixed interval, so I used command lines like:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -r 5 results\%d.jpg`
```

However, the interval between the first few frames are different from that of the rest.

For example, if I do both `ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -r 25 -t 5 test\%d.jpg` and `ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -r 5 -t 5 test2\%d.jpg` (for a fps 25 video), I would expect that the results in `test2` is a subsequence of the results in `test` with interval 5. However what I got are:
[Screenshot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC28c.jpg)

From the thumbnails, it is obvious that images 112~125 in `test` does not appear in `test2`. Some close inspection reveals that the correspondence between the two set of results are as follows:

```
test  | test2
  1&2 |   1&2 (Those two frames are identical)
  3   |   3
  4   |   4
  9   |   5
 14   |   6
 19   |   7
...   | ...
104   |  24
109   |  25
```

(Actually, when comparing the last frames, I just realized the results in `test` had too much mosaic. I fixed this by adding the option `-q:v 1`.)

As can be seen, the first few frames from `test2` actually have interval 1, instead of the expected value 5.

What is the reason for this behavior, and how to fix it?

In case someone want to see the ffmpeg outputs:

```
PS C:\Users\<username>\Documents\New folder> ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -r 25 -t 5 test\%d.jpg
ffmpeg version N-50911-g9efcfbe Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 13 2013 21:26:48 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfi
g --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libg
sm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --ena
ble-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-lib
twolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxa
vs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 19.100 / 52. 19.100
  libavcodec     55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavformat    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavdevice    54.  4.100 / 54.  4.100
  libavfilter     3. 45.103 /  3. 45.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2015-05-05 04:46:16
  Duration: 00:49:04.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 386 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 524x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 131:90], 287
 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-05-05 04:46:21
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Output #0, image2, to 'test\%d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf55.0.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 524x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 131:90], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mjpeg)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  125 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:05.00 bitrate=N/A
video:1140kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.001884%
PS C:\Users\<username>\Documents\New folder> ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -r 5 -t 5 test2\%d.jpg
ffmpeg version N-50911-g9efcfbe Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 13 2013 21:26:48 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfi
g --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libg
sm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --ena
ble-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-lib
twolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxa
vs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 19.100 / 52. 19.100
  libavcodec     55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavformat    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavdevice    54.  4.100 / 54.  4.100
  libavfilter     3. 45.103 /  3. 45.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2015-05-05 04:46:16
  Duration: 00:49:04.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 386 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 524x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 131:90], 287
 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-05-05 04:46:21
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Output #0, image2, to 'test2\%d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf55.0.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 524x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 131:90], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 5 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mjpeg)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   25 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:05.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=88
video:375kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.005728%
```

Comment: Try with `-filter:v fps=25` and `-filter:v fps=5` instead of `-r`

Comment: it would be interesting to run `ffprobe -show_packets` on your input file to see if it is indeed "fixed framerate" or not...

Comment: `ffmpeg version N-50911-g9efcfbe` is old and unsupported. Please upgrade.